# Is there a modern equivalent to the midfloat package?

Tags: floats, two-column

The package claims to do the wonder of placing a one-column text in a two-column document, without ejecting the page. This seems to work, but breaks when I try to place a figure within the `strip` environment (in an `sigplanconf.cls` style sheet.)

I am aware of the `multicol` package, but it does not like figures in it.

Answer (score 2):

It would be *much* clearer if you supplied a (non) working example to make your question clearer.

But I would guess from your comment that you have put `figure` environment inside the `strip`. Floating environments are not likely to work in that context, Just use `\includegraphics` directly with no surrounding `figure`. If you want a caption use the (very small) `capt-of` package so you can go `\captionof{figure}{the figure caption....}` also within the `strip`